# ScalaFX table accept generic values

Tags: scala, javafx

The problem I am having is when I'm trying to convert the code found at this tutorial http://www.scalafx.org/docs/faq_TableView_with_Custom_cell/ to accept generics

Here is my code so far

```
stage = new PrimaryStage {
title = "Warehouse Order Tracking System"
scene = new Scene {
  content = new TableView[T](ordersList) {
    val list = generateTableColums[CustomerOrder]()
    columns ++= list

}


def generateTableColums[T](): List[TableColumn[T,_]] = {
 List(new TableColumn[T, String] {
        text = "First Name"
        cellValueFactory = { _.value.asInstanceOf[Person].firstName }
        prefWidth = 250
      },
      new TableColumn[T, String]() {
        text = "Last Name"
        cellValueFactory = { _.value.asInstanceOf[Person].lastName}
        prefWidth = 250
      }

    )
}
```

The error I run into is on line 5.

```
type mismatch; found :List[scalafx.scene.control.TableColumn[com.qa.Entities.CustomerOrder, _]] 
required:scala.collection.TraversableOnce[javafx.scene.control.TableColumn[T, _]]
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Shouldn't the `T` on line 4 be `CustomerOrder`?  So it would then be `content = new TableView[CustomerOrder](ordersList) {`

Comment: Well I want the content to be able to deal with TableColumns of generic values, not limited to CustomerOrders